# Doctrine2 get index of current item in collection

Tags: doctrine-orm

how can i get the index of the current item in a loop of a doctrine2 collection? I tried the following, but it returns always the number of all items

```
$items = $element->getItems();
echo $items->count() // 12

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $items->key(); // 12
}
```

Comment: hi @Dominik Barann what you think about my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `indexOf` method:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $items->indexOf($item); // the index
}
```

Comment: Hi @DominikBarann thanks! I asked only for know about is what you are looking for, please consider to upvote is you find it useful too